# Is it safe to cast a pointer as an int to return from an int function in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, return

I'm managing a linked list and I use a `int checker(...)` function 
to return `1` if an element is found or `0` otherwise. I also have to delete elements, so while I'm checking I would like to get the address of a certain found element if it has to be deleted.

My idea is to put a "delete mode" `if(..)` that makes `checker` return  the element's address instead of `return 1;` and then use it to free the space.

Now my question is, am I going toward big problems writing `return (int)pointeraddress` in the function `checker` and then recasting it like this outside? I never tried doing a cast like this.

````
someint=checker(..);
free((pointertype)someint);```
````

Maybe it is safer to use long int for `checker`? I can't use `uintptr_t` as suggested in other questions because for this task I'm required to use only standard C library.

Comment: No, don't have this function return a pointer-hiding-in-an-int.  It's not safe, it's confusing, it's a bad idea, there's almost never a good reason to do it.  Instead, why not have the function return an actual pointer?  It can return the pointer if it's found, or `NULL` if it's not.

Comment: "I'm required to use only standard C library." `uintptr_t` is in the C standard library, in the header `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: @SteveSummit true it's better; I really don't want to debug this, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasJager Well I saw it was added on C99, the task's instructions are rather vague about this I prefer to not risk it

Comment: `long int` is no better than `int` as they can be the same size, and both can be smaller than a pointer type.

Comment: If you really need 1 function to do two different things (not good design), and return different things, use union.

Comment: @hyde I need the program to be efficient, I thought that searching an element to see if it's present and then searching again to delete it, it was a loss of time and i preferred to do it all togheter; it isn't?

Comment: Just have 2 different functions?

Comment: Just return `NULL`. `free()` won't bother with it.

Comment: @hyde what do you mean two functions? I have a delete function that has to search the specified element before deleting it of course. I don't see the point of: searching if the item is there, seeing it is there, and then re-search for it in order to delete it...once I see it is there I delete it instantly..delete calls checker and gets the address

Comment: Related, If that really is a linked list and you're using a pointer to node (whether stuffed in an `int` or not, which is a terrible idea as others have noted), you have other things to worry about. Freeing the pointer (once you settle that fiasco) may delete the node, but does nothing to fixing the linked list that at *best* now has a dangling pointer to no-mans land, and at *worst* also orphaned the entire trailing node chain following the node you just freed.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah I said free to shorten the question but I'm gonna relink the adjacent nodes before freeing of course

Comment: Is it duo-linked? If not, you *still* have a problem. If it is, then I suggest you have `checker` return `node *` rather than `int` and just be done with it. A non-null result refers to the discovered node, a null result means not-found.

Comment: @wattbatt Efficiency is a tricky concept.  Yes, searching for an element to see if it's there and then, if necessary, searching for it a second time so that you can delete it is "inefficient".  However, if the gyrations you have to go through to remove that inefficiency make your program buggy or nonportable, that's a cost to weigh against the efficiency gain.  Also, on a modern computer, for small lists, I bet you won't be able to measure the difference.  Finally, if you have lots of deletions to do, then a linked list probably wasn't the right data structure to have used in the first place.

Comment: @SteveSummit sorry for a late reply but I am interested; I am a student and for now I studied linked lists, hash tables and binary trees; the last 2 seem a bit overly complicated to me for this task, what should be a more efficient data structure? (My list is currently single-linked I don't need to go back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to cast a pointer as an int to return from an int function in C?

The cast to `int` itself is not a problem, but info may be lost for the next steps.

**An `int` is not certain to round-trip  back to an equivalent pointer.**

An `int` may lack enough bits to store all needed info about the pointer.

```
someint=checker(..);
free((pointertype)someint); // bad
```

---

**C provides optional integer types `(u)intptr_t` in standard C library.**

> I can't use uintptr_t as suggested in other questions because for this task I'm required to use only standard C library.

This is curious as `uintptr_t` ubiquitously exists in all standard C library since C99. [@Thomas Jager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631029/is-it-safe-to-cast-a-pointer-as-an-int-to-return-from-an-int-function-in-c/57635160#comment101715823_57631029)

These types are wide enough to convert an `object_pointertype --> (u)intptr_t --> object_pointertype` successfully - results in a pointer that *equates* to the original.

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

> Maybe it is safer to use long int for checker?

Perhaps, yet not really.  `long` may still be too narrow.

`long long` may be too narrow also, yet that is less likely.

---

**Converting  to an integer type may be the wrong approach**

Instead of "return 1 if an element is found or 0 otherwise.", consider
"return the address if an element is found or `NULL` otherwise."

or something like the below and store the found pointer in `*destination`,

```
bool find(void **destination, input parameters );
```

---

**`checker()` needs to indicate 2 things**

From a design standpoint, the *found* pointer, when converted to an integer, may be any value, even 0 or 1.   A robust design would simply indicate 2 independent things: pointer found, value of that pointer.   To roll those together implies some pointer is special and can never be "found".  A generic linked list would support storing and retrieving all pointers, including *null pointers*.